# How to show first row of an array and then the subsequent rows in angular2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to show just the first row of an array on a particular line, then show the rest of the array in a separate location (such as a new table or card).

For example, I have the following data:

```
public records = [{
   firstName: "Joe",
   lastName: "Smith",
   favBooks: [ "1984", "Animal Farm", "Lord of the Rings", "Where the Sidewalk Ends"]
},
{
   firstName: "Jane",
   lastName: "Jameson",
   favBooks: [ "Harry Potter", "Ender's Game", "Chronicles of Narnia"
},
{
   firstName: "Sam",
   lastName: "Baker",
   favBooks: "The Pelican Brief"
}]
```

And I want the output to appear as follows :

```css
tr.even {
  background-color: #C9D4D9;
}
th#accordian-icon 
td[name="accordian-icon"]
{
  width: 15px;
}
th#person-name 
td[name="person-name"]
{
  width: 250px;
}
th#fav-book 
td[name="fav-book"]
{
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th id="accordion-icon"></th>
    <th id="person-name">Name</th>
    <th id="fav-book">Favorite Book(s)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td name="accordion-icon">+</td>
    <td name="person-name">Joe Smith</td>
    <td name="fav-book">1984</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td name="accordian-icon">-</td>
    <td name="person-name">Jane Jameson</td>
    <td name="fav-book">Harry Potter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td name="accordian-icon"></td>
    <td name="person-name"></td>
    <td name="fav-book">Ender's Game</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td name="accordian-icon"></td>
    <td name="person-name"></td>
    <td name="fav-book">Chronicles of Narnia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td name="accordian-icon"></td>
    <td name="person-name">Sam Baker</td>
    <td name="fav-book">The Pelican Brief</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what I have so far (where accordionToggle is an icon name):

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th id="accordion-icon"></th>
    <th id="person-name">Name</th>
    <th id="fav-book">Favorite Book(s)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let record of records; let even = even">
  <tr [ngClass]="{even: even}"
      (click)="onTabClick($event)">
    <td name="accordion-icon">
      <i class="material-icons">{{accordionToggle}}</i>
    </td>
    <td name="person-name">{{record.firstName}} {{record.lastName}}</td>
    <td name="fav-book">{{record.favBooks[0]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <template [ngIf]="showBooks">
  <tr *ngFor="let book of favBooks"
      [ngClass]="{even:even}">
    <td name="accordian-icon"></td>
    <td name="person-name"></td>
    <td name="fav-book">{{book}}</td>
  </tr>
  </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problems I'm having are:

1. Obviously, in the second set of rows, I have two bindings and that won't work.  How do I get the ngIf and the ngFor to work together?  (If I put the ngIf in a separate div that wraps the tr, the HTML treats the new set of rows as a different table in the first cell of the big table.)
     a. I fixed this issue by using the template element.
2. The first book is repeated on the second row.
3. When I click on any of the main rows (the ones with the name on it), all rows open up. I only want the row I clicked on to open. I'm sure with a bit more searching, I'll figure out how to pass the actual row being clicked on, but if there's an easy answer, I wouldn't mind it.
4. The last row only has 1 book, and does not need to be expanded. I want to make it unclickable, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That's right. You can also wrap it in `<ng-container *ngIf>` instead of `<template [ngIf]`
2. Use SlicePipe like `record.favBooks | slice: 1`
3. You can use some property like `record.opened` and switch it by clicking
4. Make sure that your `favBooks` property is always an array (see `ngOnInit` below or use `ArrayifyPipe`  pipe as described here [Does NgFor support Arrays containing one Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618016/does-ngfor-support-arrays-containing-one-object/37618139#37618139)). Then you can just make condition like `record.favBooks.length > 1` to do desired logic on your view

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5F29VXFSfT269YUwTSFN?p=preview)**

Here is the code:

**view**

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th id="accordion-icon"></th>
    <th id="person-name">Name</th>
    <th id="fav-book">Favorite Book(s)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let record of records; let even = even">
    <tr [ngClass]="{even: even, clickable: record.favBooks.length > 1}" (click)="record.favBooks.length > 1 ? record.opened = !record.opened : false">
      <td name="accordion-icon">
        <i [ngClass]="{'material-icons': record.favBooks.length > 1, opened: record.opened}"></i>
      </td>
      <td name="person-name">{{record.firstName}} {{record.lastName}}</td>
      <td name="fav-book">{{record.favBooks[0]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <template [ngIf]="record.opened && record.favBooks.length > 1">
      <tr *ngFor="let book of record.favBooks | slice: 1" [ngClass]="{even:even}">
        <td name="accordian-icon"></td>
        <td name="person-name"></td>
        <td name="fav-book">{{book}}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**component**:

```
export class AppComponent {
  records = [{
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "Smith",
    favBooks: ["1984", "Animal Farm", "Lord of the Rings", "Where the Sidewalk Ends"]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Jameson",
    favBooks: ["Harry Potter", "Ender's Game", "Chronicles of Narnia"]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sam",
    lastName: "Baker",
    favBooks: "The Pelican Brief"
  }]

  ngOnInit() {
    this.records.forEach((x: any) => {
      x.favBooks = Array.isArray(x.favBooks) ? x.favBooks : [x.favBooks];
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Even gave me a plunker page to play with the example.